How does a feed-back compressor work, in technical terms?
In a feed-back compressor, the output signal is routed to the side-chain input.
This article on SOS states that as a result, the compressor is supposed to work "smoother", with however "less precise attack and release", in comparison to a feed-forward compressor. What does it mean?
I was able to figure out that the effective ratio is lower, because the side chain signal exceeds the threshold less than the input signal. I would be however grateful for a quantitative explanation of this behavior.
What about the attack and release time? What does "less precise" mean? Is it more difficult to dial? More program dependent?
I am aware of this question, but I'm afraid it's completely misunderstood - the answers are about compressor in a feed-back loop, and that's something entirely different.


How does a feed-back compressor work, in technical terms?


In a feed-back compressor, the output signal is routed to the side-chain input.

The second quote is the answer to the first quote. That is the only difference between feed-back and feed-forward. I would say "the detector input" is more precise than "the side-chain input", but otherwise that's it. How the detector works and all other aspects of each compressor design are independent of whether it's feed-forward or feed-back.

I was able to figure out that the effective ratio is lower, because the side chain signal exceeds the threshold less than the input signal. I would be however grateful for a quantitative explanation of this behavior.

Ok, suppose we have a source signal that peaks at +6 dB (arbitrary reference point) and we send that signal to two identical compressors except one is feed-forward and the other is feed-back. We set both compressors to a 2:1 ratio with a threshold at 0 dB.
The feed-forward compressor will send the +6 dB peak to the detector which will implement the 2:1 ratio to make the output of the compressor peak at +3 dB.
The feed-back compressor will send the output to the detector, which means the ratio gets a little strange. Instead of writing a long thought experiment here, I'll ask you consider if the peak output of the feed-back compressor is +4 dB (instead of +3), then the circuit makes sense. This is because the 2:1 ratio is applied to +4 dB meaning the compressor reduces the input by 2 dB and 6 dB input - 2 dB compression = 4 dB output.
Using similar thinking, we can find that if we change the ratio to 4:1, the feed-forward compressor will peak at +1.5 dB and the feed-back compressor will peak around +3.43 dB (4:1 ratio applied to 3.43 is just over 2.57 dB of reduction).
So a feed-back compressor compresses less for the same ratio as a feed-forward compressor.

What about the attack and release time? What does "less precise" mean? Is it more difficult to dial? More program dependent?

With a feed-forward compressor, this is completely predictable. If the attack time is set to 100 microseconds, ratio back at 2:1, threshold still at 0 dB, then 100 microseconds after the input signal reaches +6 dB the compressor will be reducing the output by 3 dB.
With a feed-back compressor at the same settings, the signal will be reduced by 2 dB 100 microseconds after the output reaches +4 dB, but the output's level will be the result of compression that has been delayed by 100 microseconds. Honestly I'm not up to doing all the actual math here, and part of me suspects there might be differential equations involved if we want to get the real numbers. The point is the action of the detector is delayed but the value of the input of the detector is delayed also so you have this weird chain of delays of the changes. I wouldn't call it "more program dependent" - that's a different concept. More like the actual attack time is longer than the set attack time, similar to how the actual ratio is lower than the set ratio.

Thank you for the answer. Yes, indeed I understand technical construction of a feed-back compressor, but understanding the parameters is much less straight forward than in feed-forward one. When I asked about "program dependence", I meant to ask if the effective ratio and attack/release time can be somehow calculated, or at least estimated from the settings? Maybe some devices or plugins use compensated values on the controls?

@user1079505 As you can see I did calculate the effective ratios from the settings for a hypothetical feed-back compressor. Maybe some devices do use compensated values, I don’t know. Engineers who work on music don’t generally need exact numbers for anything except maybe in the mastering stage. Engineers who need exact numbers probably won’t use feed-back compressors. So other people might not have ever calculated exact results. But that doesn’t mean you couldn’t do it for yourself.
